# Alert notices waiting to be dispatched

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am using Ambari 2.0 and trying to configure email alerts. In the Ambari server logs I can see the following message:

> There are 5 alert notices waiting to be dispatched.

But I am not receiving any emails. Using Gmail SMTP configuration
smtp.gmail.com port 465. Is this a problem in the latest Ambari version?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting known bug...
Check BUG-30278 in the Ambari 2.0.0 Release notes http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.0.0.0/bk_releasenotes_ambari_2.0.0/content/ambari_relnotes-2.0.0.0-known-issues.html
Workaround is to restart ambari-server.